# How to ensure 2 different views are aligned and animate the same way during a spring animation?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to replicate this animation from Apple Music. Here's a video of the exact animation: https://streamable.com/guuxgo

I have attached a drag gesture to the rectangle. Whenever I do a quick tap (click on it using a finger and immediately let go), the rectangle expansion and the time label view expansion are not in sync. It feels like they are using a 2 different spring animations when they are actually the same.

I suspect that the easeInOut animation is still running to finish first even after I have released the finger before the spring animation takes over thus the weird delay?

```
struct SliderExpansionTest: View {
    @State private var isDraggedOn = false
    
    private let expansion = 1.08
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .cornerRadius(35)
                .frame(width: isDraggedOn ? 300 * expansion : 300)
                .frame(height: isDraggedOn ? 20 : 10)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                        .onChanged { _ in
                            withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                                isDraggedOn = true
                            }
                        }
                        .onEnded { _ in
                            withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.4, dampingFraction: 0.6, blendDuration: 0)) {
                                isDraggedOn = false
                            }
                        }
                )
            
            TimeLabel(isDraggedOn: $isDraggedOn)
        }
        .frame(width: isDraggedOn ? 300 * expansion : 300)
    }
}

struct TimeLabel: View {
    @Binding var isDraggedOn: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("00:00")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .fontDesign(.rounded)
                .foregroundColor(isDraggedOn ? .white : .secondary)
                .font(.system(size: isDraggedOn ? 11 : 10))
            
            Spacer()

            Text("-00:00")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .fontDesign(.rounded)
                .foregroundColor(isDraggedOn ? .white : .secondary)
                .font(.system(size: isDraggedOn ? 11 : 10))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is just a visual illusion. It just *looks* like they are not in sync because the time label is *both* being forced downwards by the bar, *and* expanding the font size. This causes the bottom of the time label to move *faster* than the bar does, making it look like they are not in sync.

Comment: Does it still look "not in sync" if you use a fixed font size? If so, what kind of effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Trying to recreate the scrubber from Apple Music in iOS 16. The Scrubber from Apple Music has a similar looking scrubber but that one does not have this weird effect though.

Comment: Can you post a gif of that? I don't have an Apple Music subscription.

Comment: Here you go: https://streamable.com/guuxgo

Comment: I changed `easeInOut` to also be a `spring` animation, and as far as I can tell, it looks pretty similar.